# How do I list cmake user-definable variables?

Tags: cmake

I want to list things that I can set with `-D` at configure time, like with `ccmake` or `cmake-gui`, but non-interactively.

How do I do it, apart from trying to capture `ccmake`'s output or parsing cmake's files myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the following in your binary output directory:

```
cmake -LH .
```

See [CMake's documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#options):

> `-L[A][H]` List non-advanced cached variables.
>
> List cache variables will run CMake and list all the variables from the CMake cache that are not marked as `INTERNAL` or `ADVANCED`. This will effectively display current CMake settings, which can then be changed with `-D` option. Changing some of the variables may result in more variables being created.
>
> If `A` is specified, then it will display also advanced variables.
>
> If `H` is specified, it will also display help for each variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list variables from `CMakeLists.txt` file itself, you may iterate over [CACHE_VARIABLES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_dir/CACHE_VARIABLES.html) property of the directory.

For each cache variable you may check its [TYPE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_cache/TYPE.html) (using `get_property(CACHE)`). Types

- BOOL
- PATH
- FILEPATH
- STRING

correspond to variable, which is suitable for being adjusted by the user.

Also you may check cache variable's [ADVANCED](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/prop_cache/ADVANCED.html) property.

Comment: I though you want to list variables from `CMakeLists.txt` itself.

Comment: As far as I understand, `-D`-configurable variables may be from some inner or included cmake source file, so inspecting only root-level CMakeLists.txt won't reveal the full picture.

Comment: If you will read list of CACHE variables at the end of the main `CMakeLists.txt`, you will see all variables, irrespectively where they are declared.

Comment: I see some variables in `cmake . -LAH` which aren't mentioned at all in the root CMakeLists.txt.